# Matplotlib parametric surface plot unexpected results, why?

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d, surface, parametric-equations

I am trying to plot an ellipsoid so, I thought I would amend the example code for a sphere from the matplotlib 3D plotting page.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# Ellipsoid
u = np.linspace(-np.pi/2.0,np.pi/2.0,100)
v = np.linspace(-np.pi,np.pi,100)
x = 10 * np.outer(np.cos(u), np.cos(v))
y = 10 * np.outer(np.cos(u), np.sin(v))
z = 10 * np.outer(np.ones(np.size(u)), np.sin(v))


# Sphere
#u = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
#v = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 100)
#x = 10 * np.outer(np.cos(u), np.sin(v))
#y = 10 * np.outer(np.sin(u), np.sin(v))
#z = 10 * np.outer(np.ones(np.size(u)), np.cos(v))

ax.plot_surface(x, y, z,  rstride=4, cstride=4, cmap = cm.copper)
ax.set_xlabel('x-axis')
ax.set_ylabel('y-axis')
ax.set_zlabel('z-axis')
plt.show()
```

If you run the code you will see that the plot returns an aesthetically pleasing half inside out boat like surface but sadly not an ellipsoid.

Have included the *sphere* code (commented out) for comparison.

Is there something obvious here that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why did you change the parametrization? Starting with the sphere as an example, you only have to change the semi-axis lengths:

```
# Ellipsoid
u = np.linspace(0, 2.*np.pi, 100)
v = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 100)
x = 60 * np.outer(np.cos(u), np.sin(v))
y = 20 * np.outer(np.sin(u), np.sin(v))
z = 10 * np.outer(np.ones(np.size(u)), np.cos(v))
```

Comment: Yes of course! I have been completely over thinking the problem. Thank you I needed that external view

Comment: Glad that I could help. Feel free to accept this answer and/or upvote it. This will indicate to other users that your problem has been resolved.

Comment: I dont have enough rep points to upvote it but have accepted the answer, thanks again.